# Maddening auto-format behavior with Visual Studio 2019 / Resharper that I cannot disable

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2019

This started happening for me in Visual Studio 2019 but does not happen in 2017.  I cannot figure out how to stop it.

Something I do all the time is make use of Resharper's reformatting.  Suppose I have little block of code like this:

```
Scan = scan;
Target = target;
IsDone = true;
ShouldAlign = false;
```

I want to align it up to look all nice and neat.  So I select my block of code and I either use the menu or a keyboard shortcut to invoke Resharper's autoformat to line up the equals signs.  Voila!  Looks great,  Here is the reformatted code, exactly as it appears, right after I've reformatted.  Note the code is still selected:

[image: Just reformatted]

But then all I have to do is I click anywhere else in the whitespace of that document, and Boom!  Everything gets undone

[image: Right back where I started]

It is as if VS2019 runs its own "Format Selection" command when I click away  But I never did that.  (but if I manually do, it has the same effect)

However if instead of just clicking away on the whitespace I, click the ***menu*** area of Visual Studio and ***then*** click the document whitespace, no problem.  No reformat.

Just now I've just finished comparing Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 editing settings side-by-side next to each other.   I've compared every single edit/formatting/spacing setting I can possibly find.  Both Visual Studio's and Resharper's.  They are identical except in those few cases where VS 2019 has some new setting that 2017 did not.

This still happens even when all of VS2019's "automatically format" settings are off

I'm asking the same question of the Resharper folks but I think it has to do with the interaction of the two.

Is anyone else seeing anything like this?  It's driving me nuts.

Comment: In ReSharper, can you look at the following setting? Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Tabs, Indents, Alignment -> Align Similar Code in Columns -> Variables and local constants (and probably some of the neighboring settings). Is it enabled/checked?

Comment: Also, for me a notification popped open to optimize performance, settings that ReSharper is managing, one of them was to disable Visual Studio autoformat, can you check if you have this notification? Otherwise you can find the settings for this in the ReSharper settings under Environment, Performance Guide.

Comment: Yes, in both VS2017 and 2019, the setting "Variables and local constants" *is* indeed checked.  And under "Performance Guide", the notification settings for "Disable Visual Studio autoformat" was set to "Show in Status Bar" for both.  I tried setting it to "Fix Silently" but it did not help

Comment: Then I suggest you report it as a bug to Jetbrains.

Comment: Thanks.  Already done.  Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 3):

After several hours of this, I have finally discovered that that problem was neither Visual Studio nor Resharper.  It was actually a THIRD extension I use (also very common) for C++ files called Visual Assist".

VA has its own "format after paste" option.  I am guessing that it must detect the reformat/click away as a "paste" operation and it reformats it according to Visual Studio's settings.

Once I disabled that in single, Visual Assist option VS2019 (as I apparently already had in 2017) everything worked well.